# ADO.NET Oracle.DataAccess.Client bad performance

Tags: oracle, performance, ado.net

I came across to a very weird thing.

In an `Oracle DB` I have three tables. `Tab1` and `Tab2` have same structure and indexes and around 20K rows. `Tab3` has around 15M rows and an `FK` to `Tab1`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT t3.* FROM tab3 t3, tab1 t1 WHERE -- JOIN conditions and a few more
```

Executed from my `.Net` app with both `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` and `System.Data.OleDb` it takes around `30 seconds`.

If I run the same query using `tab2` instead of `tab1`, `System.Data.OleDb` performs the same way, but `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` takes for about `1,5 minutes`.

- Is there a reason for this?
- Is it a bug?
- Is there anything I can do to avoid without changing the DB's structure?

**Edit**

I've recently found the exact thing that makes the difference. One of the where clauses was with a date column.

For the parameters I was using: `DbType.DateTime` which created a parameter with `OracleDbType` and `OracleDbTypeEx` `TimeStamp`.

If I use `DbType.Date` instead, both `OracleDbType` and `OracleDbTypeEx` are `Date`. In this case, even using `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` provider, the performance is correct.

Comment: What order are you executing the second queries, OleDb first and then Oracle or the other way around?  This hints that the second result is faster because the execution plan is cached (on the server) after the first query was run, but that presupposes you ran the Oracle version prior to the Ole.

Comment: I've tried both ways. Always the same performance

Comment: That is all kinds of crazy...  this totally wouldn't logically explain the difference, and I realize how irrational this sounds, but since the only difference is the FK, can you add another FK to tab1 so it matches exactly?  Is the DDL between tab1 and tab2 *identical*?  Can you show the code for the OLEDB vs Oracle?  This is ODP.net, right?

Comment: @Hambone, Sorry the long delay. Both table's DDL are identical. If I add the FK, both providers work fine. It is ODP.net. And the code run is the same. I'm only changing the connection string.

Comment: This is a tough nut to crack without actually seeing the code run.  Two final thoughts -- 1) it may be some type of version clash between ODP.net and either your client or server  2) if you benchmark the .NET code, is the delay on the `Execute()` or the `Read()`?  I would assume it's on the execution?  Also, are you using the .NET DataTable class?

Comment: @Hambone, sorry again. The delay was on the `Read()` loop. Beside, I've just updated my question, I discovered where the problem was. Still don't know if its a bug.